# jQueryui draggable and sortable append custom html

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-ui-draggable

I have two lists, list A is sortable and list B is draggable connected to list A. I am dragging items from list B into list A.

Items in both lists have different html structures. The problem is, when I drop an item from list B to list A, it is automatically appended with its original html structure, so the final picture is sth like:

```
list A
<div class="sortableItem">bla bla</div>
<div class="sortableItem">bla ble</div>
<span class="draggableItem">bla bla</span> // This is the item coming from list B
<div class="sortableItem">blew blew</div>
.
.
.
```

I want to modify the draggable item before appending it to the sortable. How this is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `drop` event of your droppabale container, you can access to the `ui` variable containing all information about the dragged `div`.

```
$("ul:first li", $tabs).droppable({
  accept: ".sortable .dragItem",
  hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
  start: function (event, ui) {},
  stop: function (event, ui) {},
  receive: function (event, ui) {},
  drop: function (event, ui) {

    //Here you can manipulate the dragged item to create whatever you want
    var newDiv = '<div class="sortableItem">'+ui.draggable.html()+'toto</div>';

    //Add the new data to your container
    $(this).append(newDiv);
    //Or add to another container
    //$('#sortable1').append(newDiv);

    //Return true
    return true;
  }
```

Comment: That's cool, but there is no drop event in sortable. I can append a custom item in the receive event, but the original item is appended automatically anyway. Do you know of any way to prevent this?

Comment: Use ´stop´ event in sortable widget, it is called after sorting action : http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-stop